# How to get the estimator?

Tags: pr.probability, real-analysis, st.statistics

They introduce a new correlation. For $\pi\in \Pi(\mu,\nu)$ the set of coupling of two probability measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ on a Polish space $(X,d)$. The author introduces a plugin estimator.

Question: How to understand $\hat{\pi}$?

---

For the estimator of the denominator, I use the same notation as the answer.

\begin{equation*}
    D(\hat{\pi})=\sum_{y,z}d(y,z)\hat{\pi}_2(\{y\})\hat{\pi}_2(\{z\})
    =\sum_{y,z}d(y,z)\frac{1}{N^2}\sum 1[\phi(Y_n)\in\{y\}]\sum 1[\phi(Y_m)\in\{z\}]
\end{equation*}
Expand the product of these two summation,
$$
=\frac{1}{N^2}\sum_{y,z}d(y,z)(\sum_{i=1}^N 1[\phi(Y_i)\in\{y\}]1[\phi(Y_i)\in\{z\}]+\sum_{i\neq j}1[\phi(Y_i)\in\{y\}]1[\phi(Y_j)\in\{z\}] )
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\de}{\delta}$We have
\begin{equation*}
    W(\pi):=\frac{N(\pi)}{D(\pi)}, \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
    N(\pi):=\int W_1(\pi_{x_1},\nu)\mu(dx_1)=\int W_1(\pi_{x_1},\pi_2)\pi_1(dx_1),  
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
        D(\pi):=\int d(y,z)\nu(dy)\nu(dz)=\int d(y,z)\pi_2(dy)\pi_2(dz), 
\end{equation*}
$\pi_{x_1}$ is the conditional distribution of $\eta$ given $\xi=x_1$ if the joint distribution of a pair $(\xi,\eta)$ of random variables is the measure $\pi$ with marginals $\mu=\pi_1$ and $\nu=\pi_2$.

The standard notation $\de_a$ is for the Dirac delta measure supported on the singleton set $\{a\}$. So,
\begin{equation*}
    \hat{\pi}:=\frac1N\,\sum_{i=1}^N \de_{(\phi(X_i),\,\phi(Y_i))}
\end{equation*}
is the (random) probability measure such that
\begin{equation*}
    \hat{\pi}(A)=\frac1N\,\sum_{i=1}^N 1((\phi(X_i),\,\phi(Y_i))\in A) \\ 
    =\frac1N\,\sum_{i=1}^N |\{i\in\{1,\dots,N\}\colon (\phi(X_i),\,\phi(Y_i))\in A\}|
\end{equation*}
for any Borel set $A\in[0,1]^2$. Here $1(\mathcal A)$ is the indicator of an assertion $\mathcal A$, so that $1(\mathcal A)=1$ if $\mathcal A$ is true and $1(\mathcal A)=0$ if $\mathcal A$ is false.

Then for the first marginal $\hat\pi_1$ of $\hat\pi$ and each $x_1\in X=[0,1]$ we have
\begin{equation*}
    \hat\pi_1(\{x_1\})=\frac1N\,\sum_{i=1}^N 1(\phi(X_i)\in \{x_1\}) \\ 
    =\frac1N\,\sum_{i=1}^N 1(X_i\in\phi^{-1}(\{x_1\}))
    =\frac1N\,\sum_{i=1}^N 1(X_i\in G)
\end{equation*}
for $G=\phi^{-1}(\{x_1\})$,
and for the conditional distribution $\hat\pi_{x_1}$ of $\eta$ given $\xi=x_1$ if the joint distribution of a pair $(\xi,\eta)$ is $\hat\pi$ we have
\begin{equation*}
\hat\pi_{x_1}(B)=\frac{\hat\pi(\{x_1\}\times B)}{\hat\pi(\{x_1\}\times X)}, \tag{2}\label{2}
\end{equation*}
where $B$ is any Borel subset of $X=[0,1]$; if the denominator of the ratio in \eqref{2} is $0$, let $\hat\pi_{x_1}$ be an arbitrary probability measure. Next,
\begin{equation*}
    \hat\pi(\{x_1\}\times B)=\frac1N\,\sum_{i=1}^N 1(\phi(X_i)=x_1,\,\phi(Y_i)\in B) \\ 
    =\frac1N\,\sum_{i=1}^N 1(X_i\in\phi^{-1}(\{x_1\}),\,\phi(Y_i)\in B). 
\end{equation*}
So, for $G=\phi^{-1}(\{x_1\})$,
\begin{equation*}
\hat\pi_{x_1}(B)=\hat\pi_G(B):=\frac{\frac1N\,\sum_{i=1}^N 1(X_i\in G,\,\phi(Y_i)\in B)}
    {\frac1N\,\sum_{i=1}^N 1(X_i\in G)}.  \tag{3}\label{3}
\end{equation*}

So,
\begin{equation*} 
\begin{aligned}
    N(\hat\pi)&=\int W_1(\hat\pi_{x_1},\hat\pi_2)\hat\pi_1(dx_1) \\ 
    &=\sum_{x_1} W_1(\hat\pi_{x_1},\hat\pi_2)\hat\pi_1(\{x_1\}) \\ 
&   =\sum_{G\in \Phi} W_1(\hat\pi_G,\hat\pi_2)\frac1N\,\sum_{i=1}^N 1(X_i\in G) \\ 
&   =\sum_{G\in \Phi} \frac{1}{N}|i\in\{1,\dots,N\}\ \text{s.t.}\ X_i\in G|\, 
W_1(\hat{\pi}_G,\hat{\pi}_2).  
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

Also, if $d$ is the standard metric over $[0,1]$, then, as you have it in your "new edition",
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    D(\hat\pi)&=\int|y-z|\hat\pi_2(dz)\hat\pi_2(dz) \\ 
    &=\sum_{y,z}|y-z|\hat\pi_2(\{y\})\hat\pi_2(\{z\}) \\ 
    &=\sum_{y,z}|y-z|\frac{1}{N^2}\sum_{n,m=1}^N 1(\phi(Y_n)=y,\phi(Y_m)=z) \\ 
    &=\frac{1}{N^2}\sum_{n,m=1}^N \sum_{y,z}|y-z|1(\phi(Y_n)=y,\phi(Y_m)=z) \\ 
    &=\frac{1}{N^2}\sum_{n,m=1}^N |\phi(Y_n)-\phi(Y_m)|. 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

So,
\begin{equation*}
     W(\hat\pi):=\frac{N(\hat\pi)}{D(\hat\pi)}
    =\frac{\sum_{G\in \Phi} \frac{1}{N}|i\in\{1,\dots,N\}\ \text{s.t.}\ X_i\in G|\, W(\hat{\pi}_G, \hat{\pi}_2)}{\frac{1}{N^2}\sum_{n,m=1}^N|\phi(Y_n)-\phi(Y_m)|} 
\end{equation*}
is a plug-in estimator of $W(\pi)$.

Comment: @Hermi : (i) Yes, the measure $\hat\pi_G$ defined in my answer is an estimator of the measure $\pi_G$ defined in your post. (ii) Your second comment is incorrect. I have now added details on this. (iii) In your Q3, I don't know what you mean by $\hat\pi_x$. I have now added details on this as well. (iv) I don't know where you got the first formula in your latest comment from. Details on this are also added. If you have further comments, please review them carefully before making them.

Comment: I am confused at the form of $D(\hat\pi)$ at the end. Since $\hat\pi$ does not depend on $Y_{N+1}, ...$ how can $D(\hat\pi)$ depend on it?

Comment: @Hermi : I am glad that the answer is clear now. As for a plug-in estimator of $D(\pi)$, indeed you had the right idea in your "new edition", to start with a slightly different expression for $D(\pi)$. This idea is now implemented in the answer. If you have no other questions about this answer, can we wrap it up in accordance with the guidelines at https://mathoverflow.net/help/accepted-answer and https://mathoverflow.net/help/someone-answers ?

Comment: @Hermi : $|\cdot|$ is the same as in your post, where apparently $d(x,y)=|x-y|$, with $|\cdot|$ apparently denoting the absolute value.

Comment: @Hermi : In general, whatever metric $d$ is used for $W(\pi)$, the same metric will be used for $W(\hat\pi)$.

Comment: @Hermi : I will.